# How to check response headers when using go package

Tags: getstream-io

When I hit a rate limit I get an `error` implementation that tells me to check the response headers for more details.

When I inspect the package, I see errors are defined as such:

```
type APIError struct {
    Code            int                      `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Detail          string                   `json:"detail,omitempty"`
    Duration        Duration                 `json:"duration,omitempty"`
    Exception       string                   `json:"exception,omitempty"`
    ExceptionFields map[string][]interface{} `json:"exception_fields,omitempty"`
    StatusCode      int                      `json:"status_code,omitempty"`
}
```

How am I able to access the request header information from this? Will it be returned within `ExceptionFields`? I'd like to add an exponential backoff system as suggested but would like to be able to apply a smarter backoff using the response headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just seen that the latest version of `stream-go2` has a `Rate` field I can use to check this.

```
type APIError struct {
    Code            int                      `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Detail          string                   `json:"detail,omitempty"`
    Duration        Duration                 `json:"duration,omitempty"`
    Exception       string                   `json:"exception,omitempty"`
    ExceptionFields map[string][]interface{} `json:"exception_fields,omitempty"`
    StatusCode      int                      `json:"status_code,omitempty"`
    Rate            *Rate                    `json:"-"`
}
```

I'll upgrade our dependency